# ASP.NET Core : async processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

The project I am working on uses ASP.NET Core 3.1. The requirement is to create an API that returns 200 response quickly and start a async method. This async method uses objects passed by dependency injection however these injected objects get disposed after returning 200 response. Is there any workaround?

```
[HttpPost("webhook")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Webhook()
{
    MyMethodAsync();// uses DI objects passed to this controller
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: create a new scope in `MyMethodAsync` and get your services from there

Comment: Good discussion of this here: https://michaelceber.medium.com/net-core-web-api-how-to-correctly-fire-and-forget-database-commands-from-controller-end-point-cad7a879630

Comment: While it is potentially too much, you could take a look at [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io). With this you can create jobs that should run independently and you could access their current state through the job id.